# How to load hive external table or delimited file into pig?

Tags: hive, apache-pig, delimiter

I've stored a **Hive** query result to directory using

```
insert overwrite directory '/dir'
select ...
```

which creates a text-file with some delimiter, `\1` or `^A` or something..?

I'm able to create an external table from this file using

```
create external table mytable (
var1 string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\1'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/dir'
```

How do I load this result to **Pig**? I've tried

```
u = load '/dir' using PigStorage('\1') as (var1:chararray);
```

..with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out it's `PigStorage('\u0001')`